# fit the HTML5 table within the pop up window and remove horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, html, jqgrid, html-table

I had been trying to fix the size of the table within the pop up container size but could not achieve it even after checking so many solutions. Also could not wrap the text within a fixed size of the cell. I see a long horizontal scroll bar. Could any one help.

Below is my code :

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".EventLogGrid").width($(window).width());
        });
```

```css
.EventLogGrid {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
                width: 100%;
                border-color: #948E8C;
                border: thin;
              
            }
    
    
    
                .EventLogGrid td {
                    /*border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;*/
                    width: 5px;
                    border: 0.5px thin #d7d7d7;
                    text-align: left;
                    /*padding: 7px;*/
                    white-space: nowrap !important;
                    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
                    overflow: hidden !important;
                }
    
                .EventLogGrid th {
                    width: 5px;
                    border: 0.5px thin #d7d5d5;
                    background-color: #EDEDEE;
                    font-weight: 100;
                    text-align: left;
                    /*padding: 7px;*/
                }
    
                .EventLogGrid tr:nth-child(odd) {
                    background-color: #EDEDEE;
                }
    
                .EventLogGrid tr:hover td {
                    
                }
    
            .EventLogGrid body {
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="EventLogGrid" style="padding: 0px; ">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Event Type
                </th>
    
                <th>
                    Event Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Revision
                </th>
    
                <th>
                    Version
                </th>
                <th>
                    Log By
                </th>
    
                <th>
                    Log Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Organization Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Document Owner Organization
                </th>
            </tr>
    
            @foreach (var item in Model.eventLogData)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventType)
                    </td>
    
    
                    <td>
                        @item.EventDescription
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Revision)
                    </td>
    
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocVersion)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogBy)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrganizationName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumetOwnerOrganizationName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
      
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you know about bootstrap.js? If you know then you can use bootstrap.js to remove horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Just add three links to your head tag and apply '**dataTable**' class to you table that will remove horizontal scroll

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$(".EventLogGrid").width($(window).width());
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .EventLogGrid {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
        width: 96%;
        border-color: #948E8C;
        border: thin;
      }



        .EventLogGrid td {
            /*border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;*/
            width: 3px !important;
            border: 0.5px thin #d7d7d7;
            text-align: left;
            /*padding: 7px;*/
            white-space: nowrap !important;
            text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }

        .EventLogGrid th {
            width: 3px !important;
            border: 0.5px thin #d7d5d5;
            background-color: #EDEDEE;
            font-weight: 100;
            text-align: left;
            /*padding: 7px;*/
        }

        .EventLogGrid tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #EDEDEE;
        }

        .EventLogGrid tr:hover td {
        }

        .EventLogGrid body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
 <table class="EventLogGrid dataTable" style="padding: 0px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Event Type
        </th>

        <th>Event Description
        </th>
        <th>Revision
        </th>

        <th>Version
        </th>
        <th>Log By
        </th>

        <th>Log Date
        </th>
        <th>Organization Name
        </th>
        <th>Document Owner Organization
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.eventLogData)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventType)
            </td>


            <td>@item.EventDescription
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Revision)
            </td>

            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocVersion)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogBy)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogDate)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrganizationName)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>   item.DocumetOwnerOrganizationName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want show your table in a wide screen like destop or tablet. Just do this:

```
.EventLogGrid td {max-width: 5px}
```

If you want your table is responsive, you should try [these way](https://sitesforprofit.com/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns)

Comment: Could you please post your code in a live editor like plunker so that i can help you easier? And what browser are you using?

Comment: @Duannx your answer reduced the width for few columns but but some remain the same wide even if the content is less. thank you anyway

Comment: I actually wanted to use jqgrid which showed ideal output. But I wanted to create in loop,at a time three jqgrids for each tab in my view with different contents. but while doing so only the first tab showed the grid. for remaining 2 tabs nothing was created

Comment: @user7721524: If you have another choice, dont choose the table. Just use div. Use many div together and you can easily do css for them like a table.